Salesforce Internal record LightningPage Layout containing LWC donot show with LWC in Communities
In system , Inventory__c object having Account lookup , hence I have related List of Inventory on Account Tab Like below

Internally I have to add data on some fields on Inventory through related List of account while creating New Record as below
When I add these details,Through EDIT PAGE functionality on Inventory Record Page I added LWC in the screen and removed everything else , hence after saving record from Related List of Account , when I open that record I land on this page as below

It is containing LWC and Related List where I want to save the uploaded data from LWC,
I am trying to showcase this Lightning Record Page layout which has LWC , it is showing internally but the same is not visible in Community , How to implement it? In community it is showing as below, Please help how to implement this.

